# Integrate this expression containing exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I am trying to integrate

$$ \int x^a f'(x)\lambda \exp(f(x)\lambda) dx$$

I'm not that great at these things, but I noticed that $f'(x)\lambda \exp(f(x)\lambda = \frac{d}{dx} \exp(f(x)\lambda)$. I then tried several substitutions, but they all failed. Is there a way to integrate this expression?

Just for completeness:

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{xk_1}{x-c} + \frac{1}{\tilde \lambda}(1 + W_{-1}(-e^z))\\
z &= -\tilde\lambda k_2\frac{r-x}{x-c} - 1
\end{align*}

where $k_1, k_2, r, c$ are constants. $W_{-1}(\cdot)$ is the $-1$ branch of Lambert's W. In general, $\tilde \lambda$ is not equal to $\lambda$ - but the special case $\lambda = \tilde \lambda$ is useful, too.

Comment: Nothing on what $f(x)$ is?

Comment: How about Integration by parts??

Comment: @J.M. $f(x)$ is a cont. differentiable function. It involves Lambert's W, so I doubt that it is of help

Comment: I suggest that you post the version involving the Lambert function anyway. Just to give you an idea on how complicated it can get: consider the case when $f(x)=x/\lambda$ and $a=-1$...

Comment: @zxcvber I thought about it, but neitther $x^\alpha$ nor the second part of the expression is constant under integration/derivatives, or does vanish if taken derivative of. Those are situations under which I thought it to be useful - or what do you have in mind?